# JSTL filter content based on fn:contains

Tags: java, xml, jsp, jstl

I have an XML file with my database data that outputs content I need for a webpage

Currently I am working on implementing blog articles within a page using JSTL

My XML output is:

```
<articles>
  <article author="Some Author" group="City Name" id="1" title="Article Title">
    <tags>
    Accessories, Articles, Beauty, Bridal Wear, Fashion, bouquets, gowns, hair styles, make-up, make-up tips, Photography, venue,
    </tags>
    <content>
      <![CDATA[Article Content HTML]]>
    </content>
  </article>
</articles>
```

I need to filter the articles based on a specific Tag.
I've tried using the loop in this way:

```
<x:forEach select="$doc/WGBE/region/articles/article" var="filteredArticle">
  <x:if select="$filteredArticle/tags ='First Steps'">
    <li><x:out select="$filteredArticle/@title"/></li>
  </x:if>
</x:forEach>
```

but since the tags tag contains a long sting this condition fails unless I know the full string at all times.

so I tried to implement the following loop:

```
<x:forEach select="$doc/WGBE/region/articles/article" var="filteredArticle">
  <c:set var="firstSteps" value="$filteredArticle/tags"/>
  <c:if test="${fn:contains(firstSteps,'First Steps')}">
    <li><x:out select="$filteredArticle/@title"/></li>
  </c:if>
</x:forEach>
```

This throws an exception:

```
330: tag = 'if' / attribute = 'test': An error occurred while parsing custom action attribute "test" with value "${fn:contains(firstSteps,'First Steps')}": org.apache.taglibs.standard.lang.jstl.parser.ParseException: EL functions are not supported.
```

I took the sample code from here:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_function_contains.htm

I am not too familiar with JSTL syntax could someone please point me in the right direction.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Are you able to post your `web.xml` and the taglib directive at the top of your jsp?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I can not post my web.xml but here is are the taglib directives:
<%@ taglib prefix="x" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>

I addressed the problem by changing my data model, simply created another wrapper for the articles. However I wonder if my syntax was even correct in the fn:contains function.

Answer (score 0):

According to the taglib directive you've posted, you're referencing the old version of the JSTL spec.

Change:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="java.sun.com/jstl/core"; %>
```

To:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Also, ensure that the top of your `web.xml` is referencing the correct servlet spec. For `2.5` it should read:

```
<web-app version="2.5" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
```

Lastly, remove the semi-colons `;` from each of the remaining taglib directives.

Try making those changes and then see whether the original problem still exists.